# Bootstrap Nav Bar on Blogger - How to Setup

Tags: javascript, html, css

Good day to all, I just made a blog on Blogger and made changes on widths, margins etc. I found this really smooth bootsrap nav bar on codepen I tried to mess with it and I can't seem to find the solution how to make it appear like on codepen. I managed to let the dropdown menu appear but it kinda awful. I did what I could I copied all the blogger css and managed to delete the overflow:hidden in the stylesheet. Then paste it back on the advance custom css page.

https://nostalgiatrain.blogspot.com 
https://codepen.io/atelierbram/pen/vymHL

I only changed this code in the source html

```
 .tabs.widget ul,.tabs.widget ul{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    /* overflow: hidden; */
    list-style: none;
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code that you wrote.

Answer (score 0):

This template on blogspot has own styles, so they are overwriting or adding some stuff which broke your styles, try to overwrite them or remove.
It's this code, remove it from skin styles:

```
.tabs-inner .widget li a {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: .6em 1.5em;
    font: normal bold 14px Arial, Tahoma, Helvetica, FreeSans, sans-serif;
    color: #444444;
    border-top: 1px solid #999999;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #999999;
    border-left: 1px solid #999999;
    height: 16px;
    line-height: 16px;
}
```